# Page cannot be found from controller even set the routes.xml

Tags: magento2, controllers

I want to add a page by the controller, I have set the routes and controller files according to the guideline. However, it still cant show the page.

app/code/Mymodule/OrderController/Controller/Page/View.php

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\OrderController\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

protected $jsonFactory;

protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
)
{
    $this->jsonFactory=$jsonFactory;
    $this->collectionFactory=$collectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.
    $collcection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getData();
    $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $data = ['object'=>$collcection];
    return $result->setData($data);


}
}
```

app/code/Mymodule/OrderController/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard2">
    <route frontName="ordercontroller" id="ordercontroller">
        <module name="Mymodule_OrderController"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

I am using Luma theme as the base and it just showed can't find the page when I access "https://xxxxxx.com/ordercontroller/page/view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app/code/Mymodule/OrderController/etc/frontend/routes.xml, `<router id="standard2">` should be changed to `<router id="standard">`.

`<router id="standard">` use for all frontend area routers.

`<router id="admin">` use for all admin area routers.